# How to update route with ui-router without calling $onInit on controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-components

I'm trying to dynamically update the URL/state on a view when a modal opens, as well as handle automatically opening the modal when the view is first shown. I'm using the 1.x version of UI Router and AnguarJS components. The issue I'm running into is when I update the state, `$onInit()` is triggered; in other words, opening the modal causes a second modal to be opened.

Here's how I'm handling changing the state:

```
showModal() {
  const modal = this.$uibModal.open({
    component: 'viewModal',
    size: 'lg'
  })
  const resetState = () => {
    console.log('resetting state ...')
    this.$state.go('.', {
      id: this.$state.params.id
    }, {
      inherit: false,
      notify: false,
      reload: false,
      location: 'replace'
    })
  }
  modal.opened.then(() => {
    console.log('opening ...')
    this.$state.go('.', {
      foo: 'bar'
    }, {
      notify: false,
      reload: false,
      location: 'replace'
    })
  })
  // The 'catch' is due to the promise being rejected with 'backdrop click'
  // when clicking on the background, though it doesn't always work, but
  // that's another issue entirely
  modal.closed.then(resetState).catch(resetState)
}
```

And here's the relevant `$onInit()` code

```
if (this.$state.params.foo) {
  this.showModal()
}
```

Here's what the route looks like

```
export default function routing ($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state({
      name: 'exampleView',
      url: '/example/{id}?foo',
      component: 'exampleComponent'
    })
}
```

I had thought setting `reload` and `notify` to `false` would prevent the reloading of the view, but that doesn't appear to be the case. Is there a better way to update the state without triggering `$onInit`? Should I just use `window.location` directly? I want users to be able to load this view with a modal opened. I don't necessarily need history support, so I'm willing to remove updating the URL when opening/closing the modal, but I'd prefer to keep it if possible.

Comment: Validate before of the `$onInit()` if the modal was opened to prevent execute that

Comment: I thought about that, but AngularUI's (Bootstrap) modal class doesn't have that functionality, so I'd need to reach into the DOM and look at the classes on the body tag. Certainly doable, but not very clean. I tried setting a property on the controller, but that doesn't persist between state changes.

Comment: Re-factor the code to have the modal operate from a service. Then the service can track the open/closed status of the modal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix ended up being relatively simple, but took awhile to track down. I updated my routing to look like this

```
export default function routing ($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state({
      name: 'exampleView',
      url: '/example/{id}?foo',
      component: 'exampleComponent',
      params: {
        foo: {
          dynamic: true
        }
      }
    })
}
```

Setting a parameter to `dynamic` will prevent any changes to the parameter from triggering a state change, according to the [docs](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/interfaces/params.paramdeclaration.html#dynamic). This is similar to the `reloadOnSearch` property applied to the state declaration, but that property is deprecated.